# Title: Extended Response Time with simple_salesforce Library's upsert method

Tags: python, fastapi, simple-salesforce

Problem Statement:

I'm encountering prolonged response times exceeding 30 seconds while using the simple_salesforce library to perform upsert operations in batches using the bulk functionality. The upsert method seems to take an extended duration to process, affecting the overall performance of my application.

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import requests
import json

# Salesforce credentials
USERNAME = 'xxx'
PASSWORD = 'yyy'
CLIENT_ID = 'zzzzzzzzz'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'a1b1c1'
token_url = ''



payload = {
            'grant_type': 'password',
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
            'username': USERNAME,
            'password': PASSWORD
        }
try:
    print('Invoking token endpoint')
    r = requests.post(
        token_url,
        headers={"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}, data=payload)

    body = r.json()
    token = body['access_token']
    print("session Id:",token)
    
    sf = Salesforce(instance_url=instance_url, session_id=token)   
    

    data = "[{"id": "1de4f46gfdvznasdsa","name": "Test-1"},{"id": "1gfsdvznasdsw324a1","name": "Test-2"},{"id": "46gfdvznasdsa2eref23","name": "Test-3"}]"
    response = sf.bulk.Account.upsert(data, 'Account')
    print("Response= ",response)   
        
    
        
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("Error in request:", str(e))
    
except Exception as e:
    print('Error: ', str(e))
```

Environment Details:
Python version: 3.10
simple_salesforce library version:1.12.5

Efforts Made:

```
1. I tried to optimize code using bulk query and operater but getting same response.
2. I tried with request package and working fine using api response time is appropriate
```

But I want to know why its taking prolonged time response while using simple-salesforce module.

Request:

I'm seeking guidance on optimizing the upsert process or suggestions to improve the performance while using the simple_salesforce library for bulk operations.

Thank you for any insights or assistance.